# HTTP response is blank

Tags: ios, json, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization, swift2

I want to send dictionary data to server but server's POST response is showing blank.

```
func HitApi(callback: (NSDictionary) -> Void){
        let mapDict = [ "1":"First", "2":"Second"]
        let json = [ "title":"ABC" , "dict": mapDict ]
        let jsonData:NSData?

        do {
            jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        }catch{
            jsonData = nil
        }


        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://myserver.com")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData

         var dict = ["output":""]

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil{
                dict["output"] = "An error"
                callback(dict)
            }
            do {

                let  data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                dict["output"] = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                callback(dict)

            }catch{
                dict["output"] = "error"
                callback(dict)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
}
```

If I use this code, then everything is going fine:

```
func HitApi(callback: (NSDictionary) -> Void){
        let dataToSend:String = "1=First&2=Second"
        let jsonData:NSData?

        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://myserver.com")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPBody = dataToSend.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

         var dict = ["output":""]

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil{
                dict["output"] = "An error"
                callback(dict)
            }
            do {

                let  data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                dict["output"] = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                callback(dict)

            }catch{
                dict["output"] = "error"
                callback(dict)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
}
```

Now server is responding fine. But if i have big nested dictionary data then this method will be fail. What is problem in my first code?

Comment: Dont use `.PrettyPrinted` when you transform your JSON into NSData for the POST body.

Comment: still not server is not accepting.

Comment: On the first on, you put for the NSJSONSerialization `dataToSend`, but I guess it's `json`. If you put only `mapDict` and it's not working, my guess is that your server is accepting POST parameter (body) and is waiting only for its GET representation (with "&" and "="). But `NSJSONSerialization` won't do it that way. If that's indeed the case, and you have some control on the server side, you may need to contact it.

Comment: In Objective-C, that's part can be found in AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m) the part of functions with AFQueryStringZzZ, but it's "private", not public method since AFNetworking 2 I think, and there may be an equivalent in the Alamofire counter part, but I don't speak enough Swift to find where they encode their GET parameter to String, but it seems to be on `ParameterEncoding.swift` file (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift)

Comment: In jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dataToSend, options: .PrettyPrinted) are you sure it should be dataToSend? I think that should be json.

Comment: check your request and response in postman. link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: it is 'json' not 'dataToSend' in first code.

Comment: postman is giving me proper responce on sending parameter in POST method.

Comment: try like this `let  data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]`

Comment: i am using swift 2.3, it doesn't work on swift 2.3

Comment: change `as? NSDictionary` to `as? [String: AnyObject]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130005/discussion-between-ashok-and-sulabh-qg).